# Shortcut for method parameter

Tags: python

I was wondering if there was a way to do something like this in Python:

```
some_method(param1="param1", param2 = somevar or None)
```

I want to pass the param2 if somevar is set, or None if it isn't. Basically I am looking for a shorter way of doing this:

```
if somevar is None:
some_method(param1="param1")
else:
some_method(param1="param1", param2=somevar)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Conditionally passing arbitrary number of default named arguments to a function.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4670665/conditionally-passing-arbitrary-number-of-default-named-arguments-to-a-function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keyword arguments default to what you provide them in your function definition.

```
def some_method(param1="param1", param2=None):
    # param1 is "param1" unless some other value is passed in.
    # param2 is None if some value is not passed for it.
```

Consider:

```
def print_values(first_value="Hello", second_value=None):
    print first_value, second_value or "World!"

print_values() #prints Hello World!
print_values(first_value="Greetings") #prints Greetings World!
print_values(second_value="You!") # prints Hello You!
print_values(first_value="Greetings", second_value="You!")
# prints Greetings You!
```

If you want to print the value of a local variable, you can do so by adding the expected variable name to your definition:

```
print first_value, special_variable_name or second_value or "World!"
```

Then, if you define a variable with that name:

```
special_variable_name = "Sean"
print_values() # prints Hello Sean
```

But don't do this -- it is unexpected, magic and *definitely* un-Pythonic -- pass the value you need in as your second parameter instead.

If you need to be able to call it with that variable without errors, then make sure to define that variable at the top of your module.

```
special_variable_name = None
# ... much code later ...
special_variable_name = "Sean" #This can be commented out
print_values(second_value=special_variable_name) # prints Hello Sean
```

Comment: The question I am asking isn't how to set an optional parameter but how to only pass the parameter when "somevar" is set.

Comment: @Hanpan -- can `somevar` be `None`, or will it always be something other than `None`?

Comment: It'll either be set or none existant. Trying to pass somevar without defining it first causes it to throw errors. Sorry if my question was unclear.

Comment: @Hanpan -- so, you want to pull the value of `somevar` if it exists in the current context and use it for `param2`?

Answer (score 2):

Probably you need something like `defined()` of php.
It is not customary in Python to check for existence of unqualified names. Having a name either defined or not and *depend on it* is bad practice.

Though you may access function's local variables as `locals()` and global vars as `globals()`; both return a dict.

So you may pass something like `locals().get('somevar', None) or globals().get('somevar', None)` to try and find `somevar` first in local context, then in global context. But I discourage you from doing that unless absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Aren't you intentionally trying to create a paradox by wanting to refer to potentially nonexistent variables? This to me seems very bad coding practice. The way Sean showed is the way to go. In your code, you should always first declare

```
somevar = None
```

so that if you pass that variable to your method it will be None if you haven't later on changed the value. Then in the method definition check if

```
param2 == None
```

This way you will always call the method

```
some_method(param1 = "param1", param2 = somevar)
```

and get the desired result.