# Always True Q object

Tags: django, django-orm, django-q

I want to create some part of Django ORM filter query dinamicly, now I can do:

```
if some:
   Obj.filter(
       some_f1=some_v1,
       f1=v1,
       f2=v2,
       f3=v3,
       f4=v4,
       ...
   )
else:
   Obj.filter(
       f1=v1,
       f2=v2,
       f3=v3,
       f4=v4,
       ...
   )
```

I want something without code duplicate like this:

```
Obj.filter(
    Q(some_f1=some_v1) if some else True,  # what to use instead of True?
    f1=v1,
    f2=v2,
    f3=v3,
    f4=v4,
    ...
)
```

Comment: Is there a way to do an always false Q object?

Comment: It doesn't work. I've created the question asking how to create an always False Q object http://stackoverflow.com/q/35893867/247696

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here's one way to get an always true Q object:

```
always_true = ~Q(pk__in=[])
```

The ORM optimizer recognises that `Q(pk__in=[])` always evaluates to False, and the `~` negates it to make it True.

Answer (score 4):

as Alasdair answered in comment:

```
Obj.filter(
    Q(some_f1=some_v1) if some else Q(), 
    f1=v1,
    f2=v2,
    f3=v3,
    f4=v4,
    ...
)
```

Comment: Note that `Q()` isn't really an always true Q object, it's an empty Q object. For example, both `Foobar.objects.filter(Q())` and `Foobar.objects.exclude(Q())` return all objects.

Comment: `Q()` is a bad idea. In addition to what @Flimm mentioned, `Q()` also gets optimised out of e.g. `Foobar.objects.filter(Q() | CONDITION)` and we're effectively left with `Foobar.objects.filter(CONDITION)`.

Comment: If you want an always true `Q()`, then `~Q(pk__in=[])` as suggested by Jonathan [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35894763/113962) seems to be the best solution. However in the code in the question, the OP *does* want the `Q()` to be optimised out, so I disagree with @DartDega that it's a bad idea.

Answer (score 3):

Try this;

```
conditions = {'f1':f1,'f2':f2, 'f3':f3}
if some:
    conditions['some_f1'] = some_v1

Obj.objects.filter(**conditions)
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4670697/3479125) answer we can make conditional argument passing

```
Obj.filter(
    *( (Q(some_f1=some_v1),) if some  else ()),    
    f1=v1,
    f2=v2,
    f3=v3,
    f4=v4,
    ...
)
```

So, if `some` is `True` we add tuple `(Q(some_f1=some_v1),)`  to arguments list, in other case we add empty tuple `()`, also we need to wrap it in `*()`, as always when we passing tuple of non-keyword args

Comment: It would be great if you add some comments about the logic behind this trick (:

Comment: Personally, I think that moving the if else logic out of the `filter()` makes it easier to read. But if you prefer this style, you can use a `Q()` with no arguments: `Q(some_f1=some_v1) if condition else Q()`. This avoids the need for `*args` unpacking.

Comment: Alasdair, your comment is the answer, please post

Answer (score 1):

An "always true" Q object is equivalent to No Q object when using AND (basic filter syntax; i.e. `x and True == x`), thus a DRYer alternative for your use case is as follows:

```
filters = dict(f1=v1,
               f2=v2,
               f3=v3,
               f4=v4,
               ...)
if some:
    filters['some_f1'] = some_v1

qs = obj.filter(**filters)
```

Modify according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Since [QuerySets are lazy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy), you can create the default filter, and then add others base on your conditions. Django won't run the query until the QuerySet is evaluated (for example, iterating through it in a for loop)

```
filtered_objects = Obj.filter(
    some_f1=some_v1,
    f1=v1,
    f2=v2,
    f3=v3,
    f4=v4,
    ...
)
if some:
    filtered_objects.filter(some_f1=some_v1)
```

Comment: Note that this can give subtly different results (versus putting all filters in one filter call) when used on related fields.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54830561/3124256 for an alternative.