# Always False Q object

Tags: django

In Django ORM, how does one go about creating a Q object that is always False?

This is similar to the question about [always True Q objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33517468/247696), but the other way round.

Note that this doesn't work:

```
Foobar.objects.filter(~Q()) # returns a queryset which gives all objects
```

---

Why do I want a Q object instead of the simple False value? So that I can combine it with other Q values, like this for example:

```
condition = always_true_q_object
if something_or_other:
    condition = condition | foobar_that_returns_a_q_object()
if something_or_other2:
    condition = condition | foobar_that_returns_a_q_object2()
```

Comment: Do you mean `.exclude(Q())`?..

Comment: @Sayse I can see how that would work. However, I want a Q object that always is False, so that I can use it later to combine with other Q objects with AND and OR logic.

Comment: It might help if you could show a [mcve] of exactly what it is you're looking for

Comment: Why would you want a query that always evaluates to False instead of using `False` itself?

Comment: @Sayse: I already have in the question post. I want a Q object XXXX such that `Foobar.objects.filter(XXX)` always returns a queryset that gives zero results.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the question... I can't see how this `false` object will be any different than ignoring this parameter altogether and constructing a specific query. Although, Alasdairs answer appears to provide a valid solution

Comment: @Flimm This behaviour doesn't seem [natural](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TOOWTDI). At some point you have to decide whether to add the filter or not and then you can just return your response.

Comment: It's pretty common pattern in my experience. Outside of ORM-land, I've seen `1=0` and `1=1` used for this purpose in MySQL queries. It seems silly that I can't do this simply in Django.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using `Q(pk__in=[])` seems to be a good way to represent this idiom.

As indicated by @fwip and comments below: Django's ORM nicely recognises this case, knowing this always evaluates to `FALSE`.  For example:

```py
FooBar.objects.filter(Q(pk__in=[]))
```

correctly returns an empty `QuerySet` without involving any round trip to the database.  While:

```py
FooBar.objects.filter(
  (Q(pk__in=[]) & Q(foo="bar")) |
  Q(hello="world")
)
```

is optimised down to:

```py
FooBar.objects.filter(
  Q(hello="world")
)
```

i.e. it recognises that `Q(pk__in=[])` is always `FALSE`, hence the `AND` condition can never be `TRUE`, so is removed.

To see what queries are actually sent to the database, see: [How can I see the raw SQL queries Django is running?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1074212/1358308)

Answer (score 17):

**Note: Sam's answer is better. I've left this answer here instead of deleting it so that you can see the 'more hacky' answer that Sam is referring to**

## Original answer:

What about:

```
Q(pk__isnull=True)
```

or

```
Q(pk=None)
```

It seems hacky, but it appears to work. For example:

```
>>> FooBar.objects.filter(Q(x=10)|Q(pk__isnull=True))
[<FooBar: FooBar object>, ...]
>>> FooBar.objects.filter(Q(x=10)&Q(pk__isnull=True))
[]
```

However, note that it doesn't work as you might expect when OR'd with an empty `Q()`.

```
>>> FooBar.objects.filter(Q()|Q(pk__isnull=True))
[]
```

The solution to this might be to use `Q(pk__isnull=False)` as the 'always True Q'.

```
>>> FooBar.objects.filter(Q(pk__isnull=False)|Q(pk__isnull=True))
[<FooBar: FooBar object>, ...]
>>> FooBar.objects.filter(Q(pk__isnull=False)&Q(pk__isnull=True))
[]
```

Comment: It should be noted that "it doesn't work as you might expect when OR'd with an empty `Q()`" not because of limitations of the `Q(pk=None)` approach, but simply because `Q()` is not a "True Q object". It's "an empty Q object". It doesn't add any new information to the system. It doesn't change anything. `Q()|[anything]` is equivalent to `[anything]`.

Comment: @LudwikTrammer that's a good explanation of why it doesn't work. So I think a possible solution might be to use `Q(pk__isnull=False)` instead of `Q()` for the 'True Q object'.

Comment: This answer probably shouldn't be accepted over the `Q(pk__in=[])` answers. The Django optimizer (correctly) does not recognize `Q(pk__isnull=True)` or `Q(pk=None)` as expressions that always return empty. The `pk` field can be overridden, so it isn't a safe assumption. This results in messier queries than the other answers.

Answer (score 12):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, but Sam Mason's answer (`Q(pk__in=[])`) has the advantage that it doesn't even perform a database query if used alone. Django (v1.10) seems smart enough to recognize that the condition is unsatisfiable, and returns an empty queryset without asking the database.

```
$ ./manage.py shell_plus

In [1]: from django.db import connection

In [2]: FooBar.objects.filter(Q(pk__in=[]))
Out[2]: <QuerySet []>

In [3]: connection.queries
Out[3]: []
```

Comment: When it is just a comment, dont misuse the answer button. So maybe you want to improve a bit more ... to turn this into a real answer.

Comment: Okay, but Sam answered the question first, I just had an addendum to his answer. I don't really know what you mean by "improve a bit more" - my reputation? My knowledge? I just want to add a helpful tidbit so other people can benefit.

Comment: It's nice to note that the optimizer will correctly simplify complex expressions. Queries for `( Q(pk__in=[]) & Q(foo="bar") ) | Q(hello="world")` will simplify the condition to `WHERE "hello" = world`. It also works with tilde `~` negations.