# Django how to make dynamically OR queries with ORM

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

Here is my SQL query:

```
all_or_conditions = []
if request.GET.get('filter_phone'):
      all_or_conditions.append("phone='"+request.GET.get('filter_phone')+"'")
if request.GET.get('filter_email'):
      all_or_conditions.append("email='"+request.GET.get('filter_email')+"'")
if request.GET.get('filter_whatsapp'):
      all_or_conditions.append("whatsapp='"+request.GET.get('filter_whatsapp')+"'")

sql_query = "SELECT * FROM app_table WHERE " + " OR ".join(all_or_conditions)
```

So if only one email is set `sql_query` will be like:

```
SELECT * FROM app_table WHERE email='user@email.com'
```

if email and whatspp

```
SELECT * FROM app_table WHERE email='user@email.com' OR whatsapp='15557776655'
```

So the question is, is it possible to make such query with Django ORM not by performing RAW queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a `Q` object dynamically:

```
phone = request.GET.get('filter_phone')
email = request.GET.get('filter_email')
whatsapp = request.GET.get('filter_whatsapp')

q = Q(pk__in=[])  
# something result-less, not to have an empty query in your disjunction 
# that would hold for all entries

if phone:
    q |= Q(phone=phone)
if email:
    q |= Q(email=email)
if whatsapp:
    q |= Q(whatsapp=whatsapp)

qs = qs.filter(q)
```

See [Always False Q object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35893867/always-false-q-object) .

Comment: Awesome, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use `from django.db.models import Q`

```
some_model.objects.get(Q(email="email") | Q(whatsapp="1234567") | Q(phone="2341"), some_field="value")
```

you can also use `&` instead of `|` for `and` operation.

Read the documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) for more details.

Comment: Thanks, but you forgot that query creates based on request:
it can be only by email or only by whatsapp and with all fields at once

and there is a more fields for filtering, so your code is not useful for me